# performSelectorOnMainThread works but performSelector doesn't why?

Tags: iphone

I have a selector and target, and calls the method like this

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)selector withObject:nil waitUntilDone:FALSE];
```

But after I changed it to this, it doesn't work

```
[target performSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Any ideas?

I don't want to perform that task on the main thread because it lags the UI.

By doesn't work I mean that it simply doesn't call the method. I have it im debu mode in simulator and confirmed that it was not called.

Comment: can you be more specific about "doesn't work"?  why are you casting selector to a (SEL), isn't it one already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you're sending the message from another than the main thread. Cocoa just builds a run loop for the main thread, for other threads you have to build one yourself. The method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` schedules the message for the next pass through the run loop. So if there is none, the message will not be sent.

For your case, why don't you just send `[target performSelector:selector withObject:nil];`? You dont need a run loop for that and the message will be sent immediately (on the same thread).

Comment: Life save. That's very tricky, was not documented well at all!